# Generate a sequence of two numbers printing even and odd number?

Tags: java, multithreading

There are 2 threads one printing { 1,3,5,7,9} .Another printing  {2,4,6,8,10}

I want to print {1,2,3,4,5,6,7...}

```
package com.oddnumber.threading;

public class NumberPrint implements Runnable {
  int number=1;
  private Object lock = new Object();
  private volatile boolean isOdd = false;

  public void generateEvenNumbers(int number) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (isOdd == false) {
        lock.wait();
      }
      System.out.println("even" + number);
      isOdd = false;
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void generateOddNumbers(int number) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (isOdd == true) {
        lock.wait();
      }
      System.out.println("odd" + number);
      isOdd = true;
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      if(number%2 == 0) {
        try {
          generateEvenNumbers(number);
          number++;
          Thread.sleep(1112);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      } else {
        try {
          generateOddNumbers(number);
          number++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }     
}
```

I have executed it using:

```
package com.oddnumber.threading;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberPrint n1 = new NumberPrint();
    NumberPrint n2 = new NumberPrint();
    new Thread(n1).start();
    new Thread(n2).start();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
 4
 4
 5
 5
 6
 6
 7
 8
 7
 8
 9
 9
 10
```

Each number is printing twice, but why is the number variable is not shared between the two threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each instance of the NumberPrint class has its own instance of the lock object.  Using synchronized on the two different instances will have no effect.  The methods must use the same object.  One way would be for the main() method to create an instance of an object and pass it to the NumberPrint constructor so that there is only one instance that all the methods use to synch on.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your variables in `NumberPrint` `static` (and probably `static volatile`) so that they will be shared between the two threads.  This should be done for `number`, `lock`, and `isOdd`.  If that's all you do, though, your output will be {1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...} because the two threads both read `number` as quickly as they can when they start running, without any synchronization.  The best solution seems to be to make sure `generateEvenNumbers` and `generateOddNumbers` read the shared `number` after they synchronize--which means getting rid of the `number` parameter to those routines, and then when they read `number` it will be the shared one.

Answer (score 0):

As NormR said the two threads have to share the same lock, eg:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object lock = new Object();

        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new GeneratorHandler(lock, new EvenGenerator()));
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new GeneratorHandler(lock, new OddGenerator()));

        oddThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        evenThread.start();

    }

}
```

---

```
public interface Generator {
    public int generate();
}
```

---

```
public class EvenGenerator implements Generator {
    int n = 0;

    @Override
    public int generate() {
        return n += 2;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class OddGenerator implements Generator {
    int n = -1;

    @Override
    public int generate() {
        return n += 2;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GeneratorHandler implements Runnable {

    private Object lock;
    private Generator generator;

    public GeneratorHandler(Object lock, Generator generator) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            synchronized(lock){
                System.out.println(generator.generate());
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PrintOnetoTen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            SharedPrinter sp = new SharedPrinter();

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            executor.submit(new EvenNumberProducer(sp, 10));
            executor.submit(new OddNumberProducer(sp , 10));
            executor.shutdown();
        }

    }


    class SharedPrinter {

        Semaphore semEven = new Semaphore(0);
        Semaphore semOdd = new Semaphore(1);

        public void printEvenNumber(int num) {
            try {
                semEven.acquire();
            }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

            }
            System.out.println("Thread 2 - Number : " +num);
            semOdd.release();
        }

        public void printOddNumber(int num) {
            try {
                semOdd.acquire();
            }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

            }
            System.out.println("Thread 1 - Number : " +num);
                semEven.release();
        }

    }

    class EvenNumberProducer implements Runnable {

        SharedPrinter sp;
        int index;

        EvenNumberProducer(SharedPrinter sp , int index) {
            this.sp = sp;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 2 ; i <= index ; i = i + 2 ) {
                sp.printEvenNumber(i);
            }
        }
    }

    class OddNumberProducer implements Runnable{
        SharedPrinter sp;
        int index;

        OddNumberProducer(SharedPrinter sp , int index) {
            this.sp = sp;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1 ; i <= index ; i = i + 2) {
                sp.printOddNumber(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

***Output of the programs is :***

```
    Thread 1 - Number : 1

    Thread 2 - Number : 2

    Thread 1 - Number : 3

    Thread 2 - Number : 4

    Thread 1 - Number : 5

    Thread 2 - Number : 6

    Thread 1 - Number : 7

    Thread 2 - Number : 8

    Thread 1 - Number : 9

    Thread 2 - Number : 10
```